# Could Apple Airtags interfere with aircraft communication and navigation systems?

Tags: safety, navigation, radio-communications

[German media reports](https://www.watson.de/leben/urlaub%20&%20freizeit/879935671-airtags-im-flugzeug-koffer-erlaubt-oder-verboten-lufthansa-aeussert-sich) that Lufthansa has [banned Airtags](https://onemileatatime.com/news/lufthansa-bans-airtags/) in checked bags:

> This is specifically because of the transmission function.

> Lufthansa claims that the transmission function needs to be turned off during flight when in checked luggage, just as is required for cell phones, laptops, etc.

Factoring in frequencies, transmission power (and any other relevant factors), it is possible Airtags could interfere with aircraft navigation and communication systems? Given other airlines haven't banned them, it is curious why only one would choose to do so.

Comment: They’re low-power Bluetooth devices, similar to earbuds.  Complete non-issue.

Comment: Surely it has nothing to do with people using air tags to track their luggage which Lufthansa lost and cannot find.

Answer (score 3):

No, the Air Tags will not interfere with aircraft avionics and communication systems. In response to Lufthansa's ban, Apple stated that its Air Tags are compliant with all aviation safety regulations, and the statement was supported by both the FAA and NTSB in the United States and in Europe, the EASA stated it does not ban or allow the device, it is up to each airline to decide. Since Lufthansa has [backtracked](https://simpleflying.com/lufthansa-backtracks-on-apple-airtag-ban/) on its ban and again allows Air Tags in checked bags citing an ICAO guideline for issuing the ban in the first place.

Comment: Air Tags use 2.4GHz (Bluetooth-LE), 13.56MHz (NFC), and 6.5-8GHz (Ultra-Wideband). These are the same frequencies as any modern cellphone.

Comment: @DavidKryzaniak And to what extent is an airliner's fuselage a resonant cavity?